# Trying to to do npm install on the angular project file

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, npm, node-modules, npm-install

Not able to do npm install on a project folder, getting the following error, not sure if it related to version or libraries

```
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',

npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Program Files\Python39\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Python39\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];       
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:399:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:526:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commamds

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

## clean npm cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

## delete node modules and package-lock.json

```
npm rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json
```

## retry installing dependencies

```
npm install
```

Comment: Issue is still persistent. Getting error while running 
npm rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json
this.
ActualIy I got  folder externally, now trying to run npm on it but not able to due to this error. can you help me more on this?

Comment: can you try to delete node_modules & package-lock.json manually?